# How to use MatDialog.open inside operator iif

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cdk, mat-dialog

I just ran into the following issue

```
function doMagic(foo: boolean) {
    return iif(
        () => foo,
        this.dialog.open(MyComponent).afterClosed(),
        of(true)
    ).pipe( .... );
}
```

So, if `foo === true` I want to open the dialog, if false, I don't and `true` is emitted.

Now, the problem with this code is, that no matter what `foo` is, the dialog will always open. Should I replace `iif` with an if/else, something like this

```
function doMagic(foo: boolean) {
    let stream = of(true);

    if (foo) {
        stream = this.dialog.....
    }

    stream.pipe(...);
}
```

or is there a way I can fix my initial code, such that, for example, the `open` function behaves more as a stream.

Comment: use `defer`, defer(() => this.dialog.open(MyComponent).afterClosed())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **iif** introduces unnecessary complication.  *The only point of using it is when you need to delay the execution of the condition until the moment of subscription.*  Your example doesn't need that and even if it did, using **defer** with a condition inside of it will be cleaner and more flexible.  In fact, [if you check the source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/718be5bb8db5bb07ec9e4da8b5741e579bba6e62/src/internal/observable/iif.ts#L83-L85), you'll see that **iif** just wraps **defer**.  IMO, just avoid the **iif** operator entirely.

Your second example is fine, and you could make things a bit more concise with the conditional ternary operator.

```
doMagic(foo: boolean) {
  const stream$ = (foo) ? this.dialog.open(MyComponent).afterClosed() : of(true);
  return stream$.pipe(/* .... */);
}
```

Here's an example using defer where **foo** is some class variable.  When somebody subscribes to the stream, the value of **foo** is checked then.

```
doMagic() {
  return defer(() => (this.foo) ? this.dialog.open(MyComponent).afterClosed() : of(true))
    .pipe(/* .... */);
}
```